# Get Azure App Settings as object using Node?

Tags: node.js, express, configuration, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to treat app settings in Azure as an object using Node/Express similar to ASP.NET Core?

For example, if my app settings are:

```
container:value1 = "Hello",
container:value2 = "World"
```

I'd like to get an object for "container" that gives me:

```
{
     value1: "Hello",
     value2: "World"
}
```

I've tried `container:value1` and `container__value1` like ASP.NET Core, but without luck.

Comment: have you looked at `./config/config.js` in the root of your app directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Azure's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure),

> **App settings**
>
> This section contains name/value pairs that your web app will load on
>   start up.
>
> - For .NET apps, these settings are injected into your .NET    configuration `AppSettings` at runtime, overriding existing settings.
> - PHP, Python, Java and Node applications can access these settings as environment variables at runtime. For each app setting, two environment variables are created; one with the name specified by the app setting entry, and another with a prefix of APPSETTING_. Both contain the same value.

So in Node.js, you can use the following line of code to get Azure App Settings.

```
process.env['container:value1']
```

Comment: This works fine and I'll mark it as the answer. But basically it doesn't seem like there's any way to automatically map Azure app settings to a hierarchical object in Node like I can with ASP.NET Core.